# Constructing Fiber Bundles with Homogeneous Spaces

Tags: lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, fiber-bundles, homogeneous-spaces

I've been looking a lot at various texts on how to construct fiber bundles, but I'm having a bit of a challenge looking at the specific case of constructing a fiber bundle $\pi:E \to M$ where $M$ is the base space (a smooth manifold), $E$ is the total space (also a smooth manifold) and each fiber is diffeomorphic (or essentially *is*) a fixed homogeneous space $F \approx G/H$.

I know that a few ways to prove that we get a smooth fiber bundle include:

1. Provide local trivializations $\Phi: U\times F \to \pi^{-1}(U)$, such that if $\Phi, \Psi$ are two such mappings whose images overlap, then the transition function $\Phi^{-1}\circ \Psi$ are smooth and the homogeneous coordinates are related by a group action.
2. Possibly obtain a quotient of the Frame bundle over $M$ using the action $G$ of the group which defines our homogeneous space $F$.
3. Use the disjoint union topology to define our total space to be $E = \bigsqcup_{p \in M} \{p\}\times F$ where we attach to each point $p\in M$ the desired fiber $F$.

While the last method listed above, using the disjoint union topology, seems like the most obvious way to do this, the homogeneous space I have in mind doesn't lend itself well to defining local trivializations since it's not clear to me how to relate the coordinate charts of $M$ to those of $F$.  In fact, it's not even clear to me how to obtain coordinate charts for $F$ (though we can certainly pick arbitrary ones if that ends up being sufficient).

I know this question might come off as a little vague, but I'd appreciate any help that one can provide in helping me prove such a construction forms a fiber bundle.

Comment: Can you ask a more specific question? What thing are you trying to prove is a fiber bundle?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan The equation in item 3, where we construct $E$ as the disjoint union of the elements $\{p\}\times F$ where $F$ is fixed homogeneous space and $p \in M$.  Can we take it for granted that any such disjoint union will yield a smooth fiber bundle structure, or do we need extra conditions relating $F$ to the base space $M$?

Comment: The equation in item 3 constructs $E$ as a set. The topology you want on $E$ is certainly not the disjoint union topology, and needs to be constructed.